# £ and other symbols not showing up

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using Mariad Pro as the font. It does support the symbol '£'. I've tried putting it in the textfield using it's ASCII (String.fromCharCode()) and I've tried embedding it directly. Inside flash it works fine. But when I run it , I see the rest of the text but the symbol.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this symbol isn't embedded. To be sure it's embedded add it to the "Also include this characters:" in the Flash IDE Font Embedding window: [image]

[here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/embed_font_example.fla) the working example for flash cs6